# Gumby align navigation with logo and toggle button

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have been messing with my code for hours to try and figure out why the navigation isn't pushing down next to the logo, and also, when I try to view the website in a mobile screen size the toggle button is way far down the page when that also needs to be in line with the logo.

I have attached two pictures to explain further.

[image: picture]

Heres my code:

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>    <html class="no-js ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!-- Consider adding an manifest.appcache: h5bp.com/d/Offline -->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"> <!--<![endif]-->
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Short Bark &amp; Sides Bexleyeath | Dog Grooming</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Welcome to Short Bark & Sides, based in Bexleyheath we are one of the few to offer amazing prices and a 5 star service." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="dog, grooming, bexleyheath, health, check, short, bark, and, sides, woof, bow, bone" />

        <!-- Mobile viewport optimized: j.mp/bplateviewport -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico" />

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gumby.css" media="screen">

        <script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="mainsection">
        <h1 class="four columns logo">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="left" src="images/logo.jpeg" alt="Logo" gumby-retina />
            </a>
        </h1>

    <div class="navbar row" id="nav2">
        <a class="toggle" gumby-trigger="#nav2 > ul" href="#"><i class="icon-menu"></i></a>
        <ul class="eight columns">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="apps.html">Our Apps</a></li>
            <li><a href="current.html">Live Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
       </div>
       </div>

    <footer>
        &copy; Short Bark & Sides 2012-2013, Website Created by <a href="http://danielsheen.co.uk">Daniel Sheen</a>
    </footer>

 <!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, fall back to local if offline -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

  <!--
  Include gumby.js followed by UI modules.
  Or concatenate and minify into a single file
  <script src="js/libs/gumby.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ui/gumby.retina.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ui/gumby.fixed.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ui/gumby.skiplink.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ui/gumby.toggleswitch.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ui/gumby.checkbox.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ui/gumby.radiobtn.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ui/gumby.tabs.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ui/jquery.validation.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/gumby.init.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="js/libs/gumby.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And the gumby.css (I've taken only the navigation code otherwise its way too long:

```
/*=====================================================
   Navigation (with dropdowns)
======================================================*/
   .navbar {
        width: 100%;
        display: inline;
        line-height: 150px;
    }
     @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar {
        position: relative;
        border: none;
    }
    .navbar .column, .navbar .columns {
        min-height: 0;
    }
    }
    .navbar.fixed {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 99999;
    }
    .navbar a.toggle {
        display: none;
    }
     @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar a.toggle {
        top: 5%;
        right: 4%;
        width: 46px;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
        color: #65a3e6;
        background: #071e37;
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 38px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        -ms-border-radius: 4px;
        -o-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-size: 1.875rem;
    }
    .navbar a.toggle:hover {
        background: #0a2a4e;
    }
    .navbar a.toggle:active, .navbar a.toggle.active {
        background: #041220;
    }
    }
    .navbar .logo {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 2.12766% 0 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 60px;
        line-height: 58px;
    }
    .navbar .logo a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0 0 0 16px;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 60px;
        line-height: 58px;
    }
     @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar .logo {
        float: left;
        display: inline;
    }
    .navbar .logo a {
        padding: 0;
    }
    .navbar .logo a img {
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    }
    .navbar ul {
        display: table;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin: 0;
        float: none;
    }
     @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar ul {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 0;
        max-height: 0;
        top: 60px;
        left: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: center;
        background: #041220;
    }
    .navbar ul.active {
        height: auto;
        max-height: 600px;
        z-index: 999999;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
        -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
        transition-duration: 0.5s;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px black;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px black;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px black;
    }
    }
    .navbar ul li {
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 60px;
        line-height: 58px;
    }
     @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar ul li {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        min-height: 50px;
        max-height: 320px;
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        border-right: 0 !important;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
        -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
        transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }
    }
    .navbar ul li > a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0 16px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        color: #65a3e6;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 2px black, 0 1px 0 black;
        height: 60px;
        line-height: 58px;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
    .navbar ul li .btn {
        border-color: black !important;
    }
    .navbar ul li.field {
        margin-bottom: 0 !important;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
     @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar ul li.field {
        padding: 0 20px;
    }
    }
    .navbar ul li.field input.search {
        background: black;
        border: none;
        color: #f2f2f2;
    }
    .navbar ul li:hover > a {
        position: relative;
        background: #868d92;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    .navbar ul li .dropdown {
        width: auto;
        min-width: 0px;
        max-width: 320px;
        height: 0;
        position: absolute;
        background: #fafafa;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 999;
    }
    .navbar ul li:hover .dropdown {
        min-height: 50px;
        max-height: 561px;
        overflow: visible;
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #041220;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
     @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar ul li .dropdown {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
        -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
    }
    .navbar ul li:hover .dropdown {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #01050a;
    }
    .navbar ul li:hover .dropdown ul {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        background: #020a13;
        min-height: 50px;
        max-height: 250px;
        height: auto;
        overflow: scroll;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
        -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
        -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
        transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }
    .navbar ul li:hover .dropdown ul li {
        min-height: 50px;
        border-bottom: #041220;
    }
    .navbar ul li:hover .dropdown ul li a {
        color: white;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #01050a;
    }
    .navbar ul li:hover .dropdown ul li a:hover {
        color: #3794e6;
    }
    }
     @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 939px) {
    .navbar > ul > li > .btn a {
        padding: 0 10px 0 10px !important;
    }
    .navbar ul > li .dropdown ul li:hover .dropdown {
        left: -320px;
    }
    }
```

If anyone can help that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

```
h1.logo{display:inline-block;}
.navbar ul.eight{display:inline-block;}
```